# ListBox of expanders

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, expander

I have ListBox of elements:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" >
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Expander Header="{Binding stuff}">
      <!-- stuff -->
      </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When one of expanders in the list is expanded, the list automatically adjust its height. When the expander is narrowed ( ?? not sure if that's the word), the height of the listbox stays the same. The effect is listbox's height can only get bigger and bigger. Is there a way to make the height adjusted to actual needed space?

By the way, I used ListBox.Resources so selected item in the listbox won't be highlighted. Can I set it in the style, so every listbox would behave so?

Comment: Is the `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewer`? The `ListBox` Height should not Grow/Shrink the `ListBoxItem` should.

Comment: No, listbox is just there. Maybe it's ListboxItem, how can I different them?

Comment: are you using grouping?

Answer (score 0):

This is due the default Itemspanel of the listbox. Try updating the itemspanel as below:

```
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <DockPanel IsItemsHost="True" LastChildFill="False"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: DockPanel displays items horizontally. I tried StackPanel, but it doesn't change a thing, after expanding it gets only bigger and doesn't come back to smaller height.